# Ant script to transfer file using just SFTP

Tags: ant, sftp

I would like to implement ant script to be able to upload a file from my system to a server using SFTP. I know of a way that uses SCP with `sftp="true"`. But since my remote server just supports SFTP, so I would just like to have plain SFTP based target in my Ant script.
I tried with Ant Maverick script that makes use of SSH but that doesn't work. Also sshexec doesn't seem to work for me.
Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ant SCP task, with the `sftp` attribute set to true, uses the SFTP protocol, not the SCP protocol.

You cannot be more SFTP than that.